# Design an interfacing circuit/address decoding circuit to interface one 4KB EPROM and two 2KB R/W memory for 8085 microprocessor?

Tags: interface, 8085

I don't know if this question is a good question to get answers or not but I am trying to honestly explain my situation.

I am studying 8085 microprocessor, so I am stumbled upon address decoding circuits. As I was looking over past year questions, I saw many questions like the one I asked above are being asked in exams.

Then, I started to read books and pdfs all over the internet and knew the uses of address decoding, and other basic concepts such as memory mapped i/0...etc

Now, my confusions are

1) How to find the ending address for these 2 devices?
 2) How to design a proper circuit for it?

This may be too broad, but I believe that many students are facing similar problems.
Though this is not the place for homework solving but due to lack of good materials around the web, I am here and I am optimistic to get a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

First have a look here: http://searle.hostei.com/grant/index.html . You will see how a decoder circuit looks like. Whatch also for additional I/O devices, each circuit has an enable or chip select active on a range of address:

[image]

> 1) How to find the ending address for these 2 devices? 2)and how to
>   design a proper circuit for it?

Arbitrary selection in the available address space for RAM, while ROM shall be at the reset vector.

> 2)and how to design a proper circuit for it?

By doing truth tables, you can separate address ranges so that you have a minimal gate count for decoder circuit. It would be nice, in your project to have RAM addresses contiguous.

https://iemcse.files.wordpress.com/2017/07/cs502snscm4.pdf

[image]
[image]